# Is it possible to paste only one column to another table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

```
wordlist table
----------------------
wordID  char memorize
---------------------------
1       我   0
2       你   0
3       哀   0
4       阿   0
5       去   0
----------------------------
user_word table
-----------------------------
userID wordID memorize
edward 2      1
anne   1      0
.
.
------------------------------
```

And what I want to do is to call new table that wordlist table & user_word table with pasted.
So if user edward is logged in, and call DB, then find all data of edward from user_word table, and paste with wordlist table and send it to front. So the pasted table should be like this. **Find same wordID and only paste memorize**

```
wordID  char memorize
---------------------------
1       我   0
2       你   1
3       哀   0
4       阿   0
5       去   0
---------------------------------
```

I have tried use join, and union but it seem not proper way. Is this impossible?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple join

```
SELECT wl.wordID, wl.char, uw.memorize
FROM wordlist wl
    JOIN user_word uw ON uw.wordID = wl.wordID
```

> You should probably remove the `memorize` column from the WordList table

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `LEFT JOIN` (where you include the user in the join condition) and then `COALESCE()` to get `memorize` e.g.

```
SELECT wl.wordID, 
       wl.char, 
       COALESCE(uw.memorize, wl.memorize) AS memorize
FROM   wordlist AS wl
       LEFT JOIN user_word AS uw 
           ON uw.wordID = wl.wordID
           AND uw.userID = 'Edward' -- Parameterise and send relevant 
                                    -- username from your application
```